# How to compile Android app source to use androidx in Android system source with Android.mk?

Tags: android, androidx

I want to `compile my Android app` with app source int the android system source.
And my app want to use `androidx` library,so, how to write the `Android.mk`,so that the app can use `androidx`？
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da4iO.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Please write your code instead of posting  a screenshot, please read rules before posting.

Comment: I want to compile my Android app with app source int the android system source.

Answer (score -1):

Find you Android studio's tool bar. Refactor->Migrate to AndroidX...

Comment: I want to compile my Android app with app source int the android system source.Without AS